# Delphi Clientdataset conversion?

Tags: delphi

I have been hounded this problem for a few days, I have two cliendatasets with data in them and I want to convert the olevariant data to string using two functions I found here in Stack Overflow.

The purpose of conversion to string is to be able to transfer the string to another location and convert it back again to olevariant and assign it to another clientdataset.

To simulate it, I created a sample app with the following partial code(see block below).

The code executes properly but my problem is when I convert the windows locale to japanese(which is the requirement), I encounter a datapacket mismatch in the data assignment on the second dataset.  but if I do this in the japanese locale:

```
clientdataset2.data := clientdataset1.data
```

it works fine. English locale, the code works just fine.

Is there a problem in the string conversion? or is there anything I can do? I really would appreciate help with this.

```
//to simulate the conversion
TempData := ClientDataSet1.Data;
TempString := OleVariantToString(ClientDataset1.Data);
TempData2 := StringToOleVariant(TempString);
ClientDataSet2.Data := TempData2; //mismatch in data packet happens here in japanese locale

//conversion functions
function TForm1.OleVariantToString(const Value: OleVariant): string;
var
  ss: TStringStream;
  Size: integer;
  Data: PByteArray;

begin
  Result := '';
  if Length(Value) = 0 then
    Exit;
  ss := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    Size := VarArrayHighBound(Value, 1) - VarArrayLowBound(Value, 1) + 1;
    Data := VarArrayLock(Value);
    try
      ss.Position := 0;
      ss.WriteBuffer(Data^, Size);
      ss.Position := 0;
      Result := ss.DataString;
    finally
      VarArrayUnlock(Value);
    end;
  finally
    ss.Free;
  end;
end;

function TForm1.StringToOleVariant(const Value: string): OleVariant;
var

  ss: TStringStream;
   MyBuffer: Pointer;

begin
  Result := null;
  if Value = '' then
    Exit;

  ss := TStringStream.Create(Value);
  try
    Result := VarArrayCreate([0, ss.Size - 1], varByte);
    MyBuffer := VarArrayLock(Result);
    try
      ss.Position := 0;
      ss.ReadBuffer(MyBuffer^, ss.Size);
    finally
      VarArrayUnlock(Result);
    end;
  finally
    ss.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streaming to string is already implemented, you can use

Writing: TClientDataSet.SaveToFile or TClientDataSet.SaveToStream

Reading: TClientDataSet.LoadFromFile or TClientDataSet.LoadFromStream

```
procedure SaveToStream(Stream: TStream; Format: TDataPacketFormat = dfBinary);
procedure SaveToFile(const FileName: string = ''; Format: TDataPacketFormat = fBinary);

procedure LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream);
procedure LoadFromFile(const FileName: string = '');
```

the TDataPacketFormat options are:

**dfBinary**: Information is encoded in binary format.
**dfXML**:Information is encoded in XML, with extended characters encoded using an escape sequence.
**dfXMLUTF8**:Information is encoded in XML, with extended characters represented using UTF8.

Using dfXMLUTF8 you should have no problems with non/ansi characters sets.

Comment: Better start your answer with *"You can use SaveToStream/LoadFromStream to transfer one client dataset to another"*... String should be ommitted in your post since OP really doesn't need it for their task.

Comment: Thank you, the saving of the data worked fine.  But now I have a side problem. should I ask it as another question?